# Should I be setting the text of my ViewModel fields in the constructor or OnAppearing methods?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code and I would like to know if I should be setting the value of VersionLabel here or in OnAppearing:

```
public HomeTabPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = vm = new HomeTabViewModel();

   // The value of App.currentVersion never changes. 
   // So should I set this text here or in OnAppearing?
   //
   vm.VersionLabel = "Version " + App.currentVersion;
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   Base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If value of the `App.CurrentVersion` Never changes it is better to assign that value directly to the `VersionLabel` Property in the `ViewModel`. Further you can Data Bind the property to a control in the `View`.

```
string VersionLabel { get; } = "Version " + App.currentVersion;
```

You can set the value from the constructor of the ViewModel but not other methods. Creating a property with only a getter makes your property read-only for any code that is outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

The Page OnAppearing method is the Lifecycle method of the page which is called right when the page is about to appear on the screen,

As the Microsoft docs say :

> Indicates that the Page is about to appear.

Now in your case, you are filling data into your ViewModel properties, which is better if you do it in the constructor as from what I see you plan on making the OnAppearing method `async` and if the property, in that case, is bound to some control it will not update that control until you run it on `MainThread`.

Goodluck

Feel free to revert in case of queries